# SQL Update command saving white space instead of text

Tags: c#, sql

The SQL update command I'm using on my website [ASP.net/C#] is saving white space instead of the actual text.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringUserData"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();

string updateSQL = "UPDATE userData SET [First Name] = @FirstName , [Last Name] = @LastName ,  [Display Name] = @DisplayName , [Phone Number] = @PhoneNumber , [Mobile Number] = @MobileNumber , [Date of Birth] = @DoB , AddressNumber = @AddNumber , AddressRoadName = @AddRoad , AddressTown = @AddTown , AddressCity = @AddCity , AddressCounty = @AddCounty , AddressPostCode = @AddPostCode WHERE (ID = @ID)";
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, connection);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname.Text);
...
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddCounty", addressCounty.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddPostCode", addressPostCode.Text);
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Also, I've noticed there's white space following values that have been written so it looks like this in the database table:

```
'username    '
```

Comment: Everything looks okay in the code you've posted. Have you used the debugger to ensure that the Text properties actually contain the values when the code executes?

Comment: Quick guess: Your name field is char() and not varchar(), specifically, if what you provided is exactly what you're getting, char(12).

Comment: @CraigW. I've gone through the debugger and even though ive entered something in one of the fields, it doesnt appear if i put a break point in before it executes the command. ideas?

Comment: What method/event is the code you've shown in? Can you include the code for the whole method?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a CHAR field with a specific set length, SQL Server will automatically pad your text with spaces to meet the specific length. You can disable this feature with [SET ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) command.

My guess is, your fields are blank and SQL is padding the blank value with 12 spaces to meet your length requirement. You can fix this one of three ways.

1) Change your CHAR(12) field to VARCHAR(12)

2) SET ANSI_PADDING to OFF when storing data

3) TRIM() the data after retrieving it from the database.

Doing any one of these three things should fix your issue.

Comment: @horHAY -- Use the debugger to make sure you actually have data to store.

Comment: yeah the white space has gone, any ideas of the update command? Still updates nothing ;x

Comment: I'm using the debugger and when I hover over the .Text.Trim() it doesnt say anything is in that box, even though ive changed it on the page before submitting.

Comment: Do you have anything in your Load Page event that would be clearing these?

Comment: When the page loads I load all the data into the textboxes, so its either being filled with a value or nothing.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sbscTg8x - It's a lot and this is my first time doing such things with websites, not sure if there's a simpler method to plugging values into boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Trim()` function on values from textboxes to remove whitespace.

```
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname.Text.Trim());
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname.Text.Trim());
...
```